# Apache UIMA Dictionary Annotator

Tags: uima, ruta

What is the difference between Uima Ruta Word List and  Uima dictionary annotation. So far frequently  Using Word List now im using dictionary annotation its also look like same as ruta word list: i fellow the below link. Please let me know difference between word list in ruta and Uima dictionary annotation.

[How to get the annotated text for a DictionaryAnnotator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443967/how-to-get-the-annotated-text-for-a-dictionaryannotator)

Answer (score 1):

The UIMA Ruta wordlists and the UIMA Dictionary Annotator from the UIMA Addons are to separate and independent components. They have been developed by different groups. The DcitionaryAnnotator is some common default analysis engine for annotating the elements of a word list. The UIMA Ruta wordlists have been added to the Ruta functionality before it was contributed to UIMA and have a different focus since they directly integrate the visibility concept of the rule matching. The main intention was to facilitate rapid prototyping/development of standard use cases without requiring additional components. Thus, the duplicated functionality.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*